# Python, JSON, Flask, HTML and Errors

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I've been looking and there's lots of questions similar but none seem to resolve my issue. I am trying to use a JSON to fill in a HTML table, i am using python 2.7 and Flask.

App.py (shortened):

```
data = s.get(base_url, verify=False).json()
return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

Now this seems to pass the item (data) as a dict, so my html is having issues reading the part i want

HTML:

```
{% for line in data.itervalues() %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ line.Name }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This now add two blank lines to my table, im 99% sure its something to do with my JSON.
JSON:

```
{"metadata":
    {"grandTotalEntities":120,
    "totalEntities":120,
    "filterCriteria":"",
    "sortCriteria":""},
 "entities":[
    {"vmId":"543645645",
    "uuid":"d0254633-8c51d3628dff",
    "Name":"test"}
    {"vmId":"543645645",
    "uuid":"d0254633-8c51d3628dff",
    "Name":"test2"}
    {"vmId":"543645645",
    "uuid":"d0254633-8c51d3628dff",
    "Name":"test3"}
```

Hope that makes sense, any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name value lies inside `entities` list so to retrieve that you'd probably need something like:

```
{% for line in data.entities %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ line.Name }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So obvious when someone points it out!! thank you worked perfectly